# How to use south datamigrations in unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-south, code-reuse

Is there a factory helper module which lets me reuse/share code in this places:

- south datamigration
- TestCase.setUp()

I find myself doing the same stuff in these two places again and again.

The south datamigration gets used to create basic data objects. Most of the time they are in the project (not in the reusable apps). Unfortunately you don't have the full code available in datamigrations, since you only have the freezed `orm`.

The reusable apps need these basic data objects for testing.

Why I don't use django fixtures?

Andrew Godwin (inventor of south):

> I generally recommend against using fixtures in heavily-changing apps
>   for this reason, and instead creating the data using ORM code in a
>   data migration.

Question: How to share/reuse code between south datamigrations and unittests?